# Details to connect my tJIRAOutput

Tags: talend

During my searching, I would like to know how to do to connect my componant to the Jira interface. Here you have :

[image]
I know my User Id and my password huh !

Here my User Id could contain a dot ? e.g. : a.b because actually my User Id contains a dot.

I don't know really the host string. I could write :

"https://jira.atlassian.com"

==> doesn't work : java.io.IOException: Reason: user is not authenticated. Record wasn't created

"https://a.b.atlassian.com"

==> doesn't work : Exception in component tJIRAOutput_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Host validation failed for URL: https://alexandre.gautier.atlassian.com
Exception during connection: java.net.UnknownHostException: alexandre.gautier.atlassian.com

Have you got a clue for this problem ? please tell me during my work...

Thanks,

Hey,

Hi I got It for this problem, i have to write the name of my company and It works. Now I have to resolve this error :

```
Exception in component tJIRAOutput_1
java.io.IOException: Reason: record is invalid
Record: 561b7536c78c4f88d80021ea
Error: {"errorMessages":["Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean] from JSON integral number; no single-int-arg constructor/factory method"]}
    at org.talend.components.jira.runtime.writer.JiraWriter.createRejectException(JiraWriter.java:198)
    at org.talend.components.jira.runtime.writer.JiraInsertWriter.handleResponse(JiraInsertWriter.java:107)
    at org.talend.components.jira.runtime.writer.JiraInsertWriter.write(JiraInsertWriter.java:84)
    at jiracsvtojiraconnector.csvtojiraconnector_0_1.CsvToJiraConnector.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(CsvToJiraConnector.java:658)
    at jiracsvtojiraconnector.csvtojiraconnector_0_1.CsvToJiraConnector.runJobInTOS(CsvToJiraConnector.java:1024)
    at jiracsvtojiraconnector.csvtojiraconnector_0_1.CsvToJiraConnector.main(CsvToJiraConnector.java:881)
[statistics] disconnected
Job CsvToJiraConnector terminé à 19:30 28/04/2017. [Code sortie=1]
```

I am searching ... but If anyone have a clue, don't hesitate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***RESOLUTION :***

As I said before, I have to write :

The name of my company instead of `jira in Host URL`.

My login when I connect on Jira platform e.g. John.Do in `User Id`.

And in your `password`, your password to enter.