# Connection is established, but status code is 404 error in Talend tJIRAInput

Tags: jira, talend, jira-rest-api, bigdata

I have talend big Data & JIRA. Now,trying to get issue details from JIRA using talend tJIRAInput. The below added my JIRA job.
[image]

If run this job, In tJIRAInput component throwing error

```
Exception in component tJIRAInput_1 (TestJob)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Host validation failed for URL: http://54.213.97.89:7340/secure/Dashboard.jspa
Connection is established, but status code is 404
    at local_project.testjob_0_1.TestJob.tJIRAInput_1Process(TestJob.java:1039)
    at local_project.testjob_0_1.TestJob.tMongoDBConnection_1Process(TestJob.java:432)
    at local_project.testjob_0_1.TestJob.runJobInTOS(TestJob.java:1726)
    at local_project.testjob_0_1.TestJob.main(TestJob.java:1575)
```

Did i missed anything in the job? How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664104/details-to-connect-my-tjiraoutput): `i have to write the name of my company and It works`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things for troubleshooting:

1. Make sure your host URL is similar to JIRA Base URL. Means, that you should remove "Dashboard.jspa" from your HOST URL.
2. Make sure your user has proper permissions against projects.